# Метка [brackets]

Tags: обсуждение, метки, переименование-метки

Полагаю, необходимо сделать основной меткой [brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets), а не [adobe-brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets). Аргументы:

1. Даже на [официальном сайте](http://brackets.io/) пишут просто «Brackets»,
2. Не говоря уже о [пользователях Stack Overflow](https://www.google.ru/#q=brackets+site:ru.stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&start=0), [не указывающих дополнительного «Adobe»](https://www.google.ru/#q=adobe+brackets+site:ru.stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&start=10).
3. Считаю не целесообразным вводить метку [brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets), обозначающую скобки, [как на английском Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/brackets/info). Если же сообщество полагает, то такая метка не излишняя, то назвать её тогда по-русски — [скобки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Поднял вопрос по [совету ув-мого Krom Stern](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507976/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-brackets#comment613345_507976).

Comment: Синонимизацию и переименование поддерживаю )

Comment: Метка про скобки точно не нужна. А вот adobe brackets хотелось бы отличать от просто скобок. Все-таки это не настолько популярный продукт, как какой-нибудь ms-windows.

Answer (score 5):

Метка [brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets) не нужна, конечно, но если "brackets" сделать меткой продукта Adobe Brackets, то найдётся уйма пользователей, которые будут использовать метку не по назначению: в коде есть скобки — добавляем метку. Вряд ли интересующиеся продуктом Adobe будут рады такому развитию событий.

Поэтому предлагаю оставить метку [adobe-brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) как есть. "Скобки" не принципиальны, да их уже и почистили, посмотрю.

Comment: > то найдётся уйма пользователей, которые будут использовать метку не по назначению —  // **[а]** можно добавить в краткое описание метки, — как часто тут делается, — чтобы метку не использовали в вопросах о скобках, / **[б]**  Необходимо сочетание трёх факторов: *а)* Пользователь неопытный, ещё не осознаёт, что подобные метки не рекомендованы, *б)* он не читает описания меток, *в)* набирает на русскоязычном сайте «скобки» по-английски, а не по-русски. // По моему мнению таковых не окажется «уйма». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Про описания могу заметить, что их мало кто читает. Можете убедиться в этом, посмотрев использование меток, первыми словами в описании которых "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ" капсом. Значительное предпочтение русской терминологии тоже не наблюдается, посмотрите на использование меток опять же. Да и в целом, закон Мёрфи всесилен.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что нужно оставить метку [adobe-brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets), но [brackets](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets) переименовать в [скобки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8).